# How does Backpack route CSS files?

Tags: php, css, routes, package, laravel-backpack

Thankfully the admin panel is displaying, but without Backpack's CSS styling.

NOTE: When I use the older version (4.1.11 instead of 4.1.13), as used in their live demo [here](https://demo.backpackforlaravel.com/), the css works!

[image: css]

[image: empty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed Backpack and it worked. The version was updated in the process, but not sure if that was the problem.

```
composer require backpack/crud:"4.1.*"
php artisan backpack:install
php artisan serve
```

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/getting-started-videos